# How to use Getopt::Long to store options in complex hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get options and store them in a hash using Getopt::Long. Below is my code.

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature "say";
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
my %model;

GetOptions(
     "model=s"        => \%model,
);

say Dumper \%model;
```

Using this method, I'm able to get only single key=value pair but I actually need a complex hash so that each key can store multiple values. Below is my current output.

```
my_code.pl -model key1=value1 -model key2=value2

output:
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value2',
          'key1' => 'value1'
        };
```

What I need is something like below.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => {
                      'value3' => 'undef'
                     },
          'key1' => {
                      'value1' => 'undef',
                      'value2' => 'undef'
                     }
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're pushing the module to its limits. But that's ok. That's why the module has the catch-all feature of using a subroutine to process your option.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature "say";
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
my %model;

sub process_opt {
  my ($name, $val) = @_;
  my ($k, $v) = split /=/, $val, 2;
  $model{$k}{$v} = undef;
}

GetOptions(
     "model=s" => \&process_opt,
);

say Dumper \%model;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways that people approach these problems:

- choose an interface, and force a tool to process it
- choose a tool, and force its interface on people

I have a chapter in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) about various configuration methods, options, and tools. It's one of the things people tend not to teach because it's not syntax or features. However, it's the high touch part of the process for the people that use what you create.

In short, the field is a mess with no standards and few best practices. I like a hybrid approach: use a tool to do most of the processing and adapt its output to the program. This way, I'm not stuck with what the tool allows.

I've always found that the `--switch key=value` interface is a bit of a mess. And, it looks like you want to be able to duplicate keys so a key can have multiple values.

You have this example:

```
% my_code.pl -model key1=value1 -model key2=value2
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value2',
          'key1' => 'value1'
        };
```

But consider this case, where key1 shows up twice:

```
% my_code.pl  --model key1=value1 --model key2=value2 --model key2=value3
```

The last value for `key2` wins, and there's not even a warning that one of the values will be ignored:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key2' => 'value3',
          'key1' => 'value1'
        };
```

First, I'd think long and hard about how you really want to get that info into your program (lest you end up like `ffmpeg`'s almost impossible interface). But, let's set that aside.

You're thinking about a hash so you reached for the hash features in [Getopt::Long](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long). But, you should uncouple the interface from the internal storage. You don't really want the command line processing tool deciding how your data structures work and you don't want the other way around either. That locks in your choice. It's nice if the tool can give you want you like, but it's better if you don't care what the tool does and as long as you get your result.

Many of my programs start with something like this subroutine call. I don't know what that subroutine call does or how it does it or what it uses to do that. I know what that it returns something my program can use. I can switch out everything and do it completely differently as long as it returns the same thing for the same input:

```
my $model = process_args( @ARGV );
```

And, this has a side benefit that I don't have to use just the command line values because I can pass that subroutine any list I like (testing, natch).

So then, what goes in there? In this case, setting aside the interface issue I mentioned earlier, what should I do?

- I know that `-model` can show up more than once
- I expect it to have an argument like `key=value`
- I want to be able to specify multiple values for a key

### Simplest thing first

So, here's a first go because this is what I tend to do right away (having struggled with and been scarred by this task for decades). I'm going to treat the arguments to `--model` as single strings and let `Getopt::Long` process them as an array. I'll post-process them later:

```
use v5.20;
use experimental qw(signatures);
use Data::Dumper;

my @args = qw(--model key=value --model key=value2 --model key2=valueA );

my $model = process_args( @args );

say Dumper $model;

sub process_args ( @args ) {
    state $rc = require Getopt::Long;

    my %config;

    Getopt::Long::GetOptionsFromArray(
        \@args,
        "model=s@" => $config{model} = [],
        );

    return \%config;
    }
```

The output shows that I have all the input, so that's a good step:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'model' => [
                       'key=value',
                       'key=value2',
                       'key2=valueA'
                     ]
        };
```

### Now adapt it for local use

Now I can massage that a bit, doing basically what [Dave Cross did in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65511724/2766176). I do a little processing after `Getopt::Long` has done it's job. It knows how to break about tokens on the command line, but I know what those tokens mean. Thus, once I have them organized, I'll be the one to interpret them:

```
use v5.26;  # for postfix deref (->@*)
sub process_args ( @args ) {
    state $rc = require Getopt::Long;

    my %config;

    Getopt::Long::GetOptionsFromArray(
        \@args,
        "model=s@" => $config{model} = [],
        );

    my %hash;
    foreach my $string ( $config{model}->@* ) {
        my( $key, $value ) = split /=/, $string, 2;
        push $hash{$key}->@*, $value;
        }

    $config{model} = \%hash;

    return \%config;
    }
```

Now I have this data structure, where each key has an array ref of values. That's not quite what you said you wanted, but I also don't know what you are doing with the multi-level hash in which all the values are undef. I think this is easier if you want to get just the value names from the command line:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'model' => {
                       'key' => [
                                  'value',
                                  'value2'
                                ],
                       'key2' => [
                                   'valueA'
                                 ]
                     }
        };
```

### Make hash of hashes

You might want to fill in your undef values later, but I tend to keep the input data separate from the generated data. For me it helps with logging and reporting. But, whatever. The trick is to make a data structure that is most suited to your task so it's easy to work with.

To get what you showed, it's a one line change. That's an important point and part of the reason I took that route. I don't have to re-engineer everything I told `Getopt::Long`:

```
sub process_args ( @args ) {
    ...

    my %hash;
    foreach my $string ( $config{model}->@* ) {
        my( $key, $value ) = split /=/, $string, 2;
        $hash{$key}{$value} = undef;  # single line change
        }

    ....
    }
```

[LordAdmira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512403/2766176) takes the long way to get to this method of handling it directly in `Getopt::Long`, where you give each specifier a code reference to further process the result. This is fine as you see it here, but I find his answer quite unwieldy to look at or maintain (although some people will think that about mine, too):

```
sub process_args ( @args ) {
    state $rc = require Getopt::Long;

    my %config;

    Getopt::Long::GetOptionsFromArray(
        \@args,
        "model=s%" => sub { my($n, $k, $v) = @_; $config{$k}{$v} = undef; }
        );

    return \%config;
    }
```

### Now the interface changes

Let's approach this from another angle. Instead of specifying `key2` twice, what if I could do it once and give it multiple values, like this:

```
% my_code.pl  --model key1=value1 --model key2=value2 --model key2=value3
% my_code.pl  --model key1=value1 --model key2=value2,value3
```

The change isn't that bad, and again, I don't need to mess with the particular tool I chose to process the command line:

```
sub process_args ( @args ) {
    ...
    my %hash;
    foreach my $string ( $config{model}->@* ) {
        my( $key, $value ) = split /=/, $string, 2;
        my @values = split /,/, $value;
        $hash{$key}{$_} = undef for @values;
        }

    ...
    }
```

The output shows I picked up multiple options with the same key, and multiple values in one option:

```
$ my_code.pl  --model key1=value1 --model key2=value2,value4 --model key2=value3
$VAR1 = {
          'model' => {
                       'key1' => {
                                   'value1' => undef
                                 },
                       'key2' => {
                                   'value2' => undef,
                                   'value3' => undef,
                                   'value4' => undef
                                 }
                     }
        };
```

### One more thing

Now, there's something (well, at least one thing) I ignored. `Getopt` and friends processing `@ARGV` and remove whatever they felt belonged to them. There can be additional arguments on the command line that don't belong to options. If that's important to you, you probably want to return the leftover bits of the arguments array:

```
my( $model, $leftovers ) = process_args( @args );

say Dumper( $model, $leftovers );

sub process_args ( @args ) {
    state $rc = require Getopt::Long;

    ...

    return \%config, \@args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By specifying a hash reference as the first argument, all of the options are assigned to that hash. It's a great way to keep all of the options together in one place. The option spec can then be put into a qw list.

You can put a code ref directly in the hash to create an option with multiple effects or to manage your key value pairs.  By specifying the `s%` option type, `Getopt::Long` will split the value for you and feed it to your code ref.

Example:

```perl
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use Getopt::Long;

our %model;
## %options must be declared seperately because it is referenced in its own definition
our %options;
%options = (
  # this code ref receives, the name, key, and value as arguments
  model => sub { my($n, $k, $v) = @_; $model{$k}{$v} = undef; },

  # set default debug level
  debug => 0,
  # set default file name
  file => "file.dat",

  # option with multi-effects, setting debug and verbose at once
  quiet => sub { @options{qw/debug verbose/} = (0, 0); },
  loud  => sub { @options{qw/debug verbose/} = (999, 1); },
);

GetOptions(\%options,
  qw/debug+ verbose! file=s length=o quiet loud model=s%/
);

our $argument = shift @ARGV;
die "missing first argument\n" unless defined $argument;

print "Starting program $0 on $argument\n" if $options{verbose};

if ($options{debug} >= 2) {
  ## Load this module only if we need it, but you must guarantee it's there or trap the error with eval{}
  require Data::Dump;
  printf "Dumping options hash\n%s\n", Data::Dump::pp(\%options);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is lost in the noise. You have so much irrelevant information the post, it's hard to discern the message.

Comment: You should be feeling sorry for yourself. I don't need the answer, but I thought you might appreciate having people actually read your answers. I've noticed a pattern of overly complex/irrelevant answers from you, and I figured you'd appreciate learning of this. Including too many irrelevant details doesn't help anyone. If the answer is just line 9 as you claim, why are there 35 lines?

Comment: (hmmm, line 9 is a comment)

Comment: I think that people appreciate fully fleshed out examples that go beyond the initial question a little.  I try to anticipate the next question that will flow from the line of reasoning.  I recall you criticizing overly minimalist answers actually.  I always appreciate actual *code* review but I don't appreciate sniping.  You have a habit of making statements as if they were empirical facts rather than just your opinion.  I always make it clear that I'm stating my opinion.  We can't know the other person's everything so it's better to be subjunctive.

Comment: Re "*I recall you criticizing overly minimalist answers actually.*" There's definitely a balance to be had. (In fact, it's possible to have both too little of the right thing and too much of the wrong thing in the same answer. It's not the case here, though) But when more than half of the code is completely irrelevant, it's a problem. It doesn't make it a bad answer (like not having certain things will), but it does make it a poor one.

Comment: For people who are having trouble with very simple things, fully fleshed out examples offer no help. They don't understand most of what you do or why you are doing it. You can include full programs, but after you explain in isolation what's actually confusing the person. Start with the answer to the particular question, then expand later in a way that they don't have to read everything to understand the targeted answer.